# Word for someone who "sees the best in others"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

At the risk of being DRY:

> What's a powerful word for someone who "*sees the best in others*"?

Comment: A life-coach perhaps? At least they should have the ability to, whether it is their true intention or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it depends on the person and his/her perspective on the matter.

For instance, someone who recognizes that humans are flawed but believes in their fundamental goodness nonetheless could be described as **forgiving**, **good-natured**, **tolerant** or **benevolent**.

Someone who has faith in others to do the right thing (and potentially doesn't see or overlooks their character flaws) could be described as **trusting** or **idealistic**.

If we, knowing as we do that people are rather nasty creatures, describe such a person from our cynical vantage point, we might call him/her **credulous**, **naive** or **unsuspecting**.

Answer (score 5):

You could call someone a [Pollyanna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollyanna). Although its meaning is a bit broader, it might be appropriate in context.

Comment: "Pollyanna" is a common idiom, but by no means a widespread one. I hear it so rarely I always forget what it means.

Comment: *Pollyanna* actually means being blindly optimistic, to a fault.  I think that should be made clear, because it's not necessarily a nice thing to call someone.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the person has a 'generous' view of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person might be said to be sanguine in nature, or possibly be a Pangloss.

Answer (score 0):

they could be called positive or optimistic

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Its so difficult to describe something so meaningful. Some words:

-viewing people through rose-tinted glasses
-perceptive
-insightful
-penetrative
-sagacious

I've tried to not repeat any of the other words already mentioned in other answers. Keep in mind that these need to be used in an appropriate context with correct words to back the words listed above.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).